# Help with residue of $\int \frac{1}{(z-3)(z^4+1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having a hard time with calculating the residue in calculating  $$\int_{\gamma} \frac {1}{(z-3)(z^4+1)}$$ where $\gamma$ is the circle of radius $2$ centered at the origin and travelled once in the counterclockwise direction. The work requires a lot of elbow grease I think (or maybe I'm doing it wrong).

What I'm doing: Using a formula from my book. I let $g(z) = 1$ and $h(z)=(z-3)(z^4+1)$. If $g(z_0) \ne 0$, $h(z_0)=0$, $h'(z_0) \ne 0$, then the residue is equal to $\frac{g(z_0)}{h'(z_0)}$. I'm using this formula for all the singularities and it looks horrible! Here's what I get:

$$Res (f,e^\frac{i \pi}{4})=\frac{1}{-4+6 \sqrt 2-6 \sqrt 2i}$$

$$Res (f,e^\frac{i 3\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{-4-6 \sqrt 2-6 \sqrt 2i}$$

$$Res (f,e^\frac{i 5\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{-4-6 \sqrt 2+6 \sqrt 2i}$$

$$Res (f,e^\frac{i 7\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{-4+6 \sqrt 2+6 \sqrt 2i}$$

Is the integral really this messy?$$\int_{\gamma} \frac {1}{(z-3)(z^4+1)}=2 \pi i \left (\frac{1}{-4+6 \sqrt 2-6 \sqrt 2i}+\frac{1}{-4-6 \sqrt 2-6 \sqrt 2i}+\frac{1}{-4-6 \sqrt 2+6 \sqrt 2i}+\frac{1}{-4+6 \sqrt 2+6 \sqrt 2i} \right )$$

Comment: It depends on the path $\gamma$

Comment: sorry editing now

Comment: @Joe fixed it now

Answer (score 3):

Hint: rationalize those nasty fractions.  Most of the terms will cancel.

Answer (score 1):

By residue theorem, since the integrand is meromorphic inside $\gamma$, the integral is indeed $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of $f$ in the sigularities contianed in $\gamma$, that are only the zeroes of $z^4+1$. These zeroes are all simple poles for the integrand, i.e. they respect the condition you wrote in terms of $g$ and $h$ so you could find residues exactly as you did (or, equivalently computing $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)f(z)$).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  You *might* find it easier if you take
$$g(z)=\frac{1}{z-3}\quad\hbox{and}\quad h(z)=z^4+1$$
and also leave the singularities in polar form.  Then the residue at $z_0$ is
$$\frac{1/(z_0-3)}{4z_0^3}=\frac{1}{4(z_0-3)z_0^3}$$
and *part* of the answer is
$$\eqalign{
  \frac{1}{4(e^{i\pi/4}-3)e^{3i\pi/4}}&+\frac{1}{4(e^{-i\pi/4}-3)e^{-3i\pi/4}}\cr
  &=-\frac{1}{4}\Bigl(\frac{1}{1+3e^{3i\pi/4}}+\frac{1}{1+3e^{-3i\pi/4}}\Bigr)\cr
  &=-\frac{1}{4}\frac{2+6\cos(3\pi/4)}{10+6\cos(3\pi/4)}\ .\cr}$$
There is still more to be done of course but perhaps it won't work out *too* badly ;-)

**Comment**.  Sometimes early courses in complex give the impression that complex numbers "should" be written in rectangular form and that polar form is some kind of "second-best option".  This is of course nonsense!